# Are the first-order theories of real addition (respectively, real multiplication) finitely axiomatizable?

Tags: model-theory

I know that the theory of the real field is not finitely axiomatizable. But what about the theories of just addition or just multiplication? That is, is $Th(\mathbb{R};+)$ finitely axiomatizable? And also, is $Th(\mathbb{R};*)$ finitely axiomatizable? If either is finitely axiomatizable, can someone provide a finite set of axioms for the theory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll prove that $Th(\mathbb{R};+)$ is **not** finitely axiomatizable; a similar argument will work for $Th(\mathbb{R};*)$.

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be a nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$, let $p_n$ denote the $n$th prime, and let $C_{p_n}$ be the group with $p_n$ elements. By Los' Theorem, the ultraproduct $$\mathcal{G}:=\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}}C_{p_n}$$ is a divisible group with no elements of finite order (other than the identity); by a quick counting argument, $\vert\mathcal{G}\vert=2^{\aleph_0}$.

But this pins down $\mathcal{G}$ entirely up to isomorphism: it's a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ with dimension continuum. The same is true for $(\mathbb{R};+)$, so we've just "accidentally" built a copy of the reals.

Why is this relevant? Well, suppose $Th(\mathbb{R};+)$ were axiomatized by a single sentence $\varphi$. Then we would obviously have $C_{p_n}\models\neg\varphi$ for each $n$ (since no finite group is elementarily equivalent to the reals), leading to a contradiction with Los' theorem.  More generally, **no structure elementarily equivalent to a nontrivial ultraproduct of finite structures is finitely axiomatizable**.

Comment: Is the theorem not saying in the limit, the object you get is iso to R. But why would that contradict that each individual $C_{p_n}$ along the way can be finite. Similarly to how a square whose choppy hypotenuse (90 degree angles) will always have perimter 2, but can have perimter = $\sqrt 2$ in the limit.

Comment: @Snared I don't understand your question. Are you familiar with ultraproduct constructions?

Comment: Yes I understand that product you've written there, and I agree that no finite group could be that product. But I don't see why it necessarily contradicts Los'

Comment: The issue is that we're assuming that there is a single sentence, $\varphi$, which axiomatizes $Th(\mathbb{R};+)$. Every sentence true in the ultraproduct, which we know is (isomorphic to) the reals, must be true in "most" of the factor structures by Los. But taking this specific $\varphi$, "most" of the factor structures would then have to have the same theory as the reals. And no finite structure is elementarily equivalent to an infinite one, so we're done. More generally, no structure elementarily equivalent to a nontrivial ultraproduct of finite structures is finitely axiomatizable.

Comment: Or, more closely matching what's in my answer, since each $C_{p_n}$ is not elementarily equivalent to $\mathbb{R}$ we get $C_{p_n}\models\neg\varphi$ for each $n$. Now Los tells us $\mathbb{R}\models\neg\varphi$, a contradiction. The idea is the same, but the structure of the argument is inverted.

Comment: See, I don't follow the "most" have to argument. Just because the behavior is infinite in the limit doesn't mean that any finite projection has to be as well.. The finite objects are different than the limit and it doesn't have to approach each property in the finite realm but could just pop into being true only over the true product over $\mathbb N$. But perhaps this argument is just going over my head and don't mind me then..

Comment: @Snared -- the fact that $\varphi$ is true in the ultraproduct iff it's true for "most" of the things we're producting is very literally the [statement of Los's theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/%C5%81o%C5%9B%27s_Theorem)

Comment: It may be true in the ultraproduct but you don't necessarily need to impose this ultraproduct axiom, if you will, on your structure, do you? For example, the logical example I gave above would not satisfy that, but it would be true when you analyze just the object in the limit. But any finite projection is false. But definitely if your logic had this ultraproduct property where if it is true by a statement in the limit, then it must be true infinitely often (obviously there is a precise definition, but vaguely), you'd be okay. But that doesn't have to hold for "most" logical structures.

Comment: @Snared I honestly can't understand your objection. Los' theorem, **the** central theorem about ultraproducts, says exactly that first-order sentences **are always** subject to this behavior. (Note that in model theory, the theory of a structure refers to the set of first-order sentences true in that structure.) If you still have questions about this, I recommend making a separate post rather than continue in this comment thread.

Comment: Ok your last comment clears this up for me and I'll be looking into that more deeply now, Thank you!